# codigo sequencial erro

Tags: php

pessoal não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar meu codigo para criar um numero sequencial alguém pode me dar uma mão? esse é o erro:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\caso.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null 
given in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\caso.php on 
line 29
string(52) "INSERT INTO caso (numero, perfil_id) VALUES (1, '4')"
```

botão para disparar a criação do numero de atendimento no BD

```
  <form action="php/adiciona-caso.php"  method="post" >
 <li><button type="submit" value="4"
 name="perfil_id" id="perfil_id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Novo Atendimento</li></a>
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="numero" id="numero">
```

adiciona caso;

```
 <?php

$caso = new caso();
$caso->setNumero($_POST["numero"]);
$caso->setPerfil(new Perfil());
$caso->setPerfil($_POST["perfil_id"]);

//var_dump($caso);exit;

 $dao = new casoDAO($conexao);

 if ($dao->insereCaso($caso)) {   
   ?>
  <?php $_SESSION["atendimento_logado"] = $atendimento["numero"];?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.location="../novo-atendimento.php"
      </script>
  <?php
```

DAO

```
function insereCaso($caso) {

                $query =  "INSERT INTO caso (numero, perfil_id) VALUES ($caso->getNumero()), '{$caso->getPerfil()}')";

 //var_dump($query);exit;
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
  $caso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
   return $caso;
     }
```

classe caso

```
class Caso
{

private $conexao;
function __construct($conexao){
    $this->conexao = $conexao;
}
public $id;
public $numero;
public $perfil;


 public function getNumero()
{
    return $this->numero;
}

public function setNumero($numero)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM caso ORDER BY numero DESC LIMIT 1");
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $ultimo  = $array["numero"];
    $numero = $ultimo+1; // Peguei o ultimo numero e somei 1
    $this->numero = $numero;
}
```

Comment: Você está misturando mysqli com mysql?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql\_\*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%c3%a3o-devemos-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: obrigado Kevin,não tinha visto isso errei ao copiar uma solução do forum. Corrigido. Obrigado Darlei, já corrigi mas continuo com alguns erros.

Answer (score 2):

O próprio erro está te dizendo o que está errado.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\caso.php on
>   line 28

O segundo erro é consequência do primeiro erro.

Experimente trocar na classe `caso` de

```php
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM caso ORDER BY numero DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Para:

```php
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM caso ORDER BY numero DESC LIMIT 1");
```

**Nota**: Seu código não está muito claro, e eu não consegui identifica de onde está vindo `$conexao`, então atente-se de injetar a conexão nos métodos que a necessitem.

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius, realmente na classe caso não havia conexão então eu criei (alterado no post)

Comment: agora o erro é esse: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Caso::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\adiciona-caso.php on line 12 and exactly 1 expected in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\caso.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\adiciona-caso.php(12): Caso->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.13-1\apache2\htdocs\mvpbx\php\caso.php on line 7

Comment: O erro está te dizendo exatamente isso `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Caso::__construct(), 0 passed`. No arquivo `adiciona caso` você está instanciando a classe `$caso = new Caso();` quando deveria ser `$caso = new Caso($conexao);`. É só ler o erro ;)